# Dell Inspiron 3537, problems with resuming from suspend with AMD Radeon HD 8800M graphics card

Tags: drivers, dell, hibernate

I installed ubuntu (12.04.04 LTS, 64 bit) on a laptop Dell Inspiron 3537. It's working great. Recently, I had some trouble with running applications through wine. Those problems were resolved once I installed some additional drivers.

The problem is, when going to System Settings > Additional Drivers, the only option there is this:

[image]

While this did fix my earlier problems with the wine applications, I'm now facing new problems - every time I close the lid, when I open it up again I see a black screen and only the mouse (but I can't move it). The computer doesn't respond to anything I do, and I have to forcibly shut it down and start again.

If I leave the computer open, and it goes to sleep, then this problem doesn't happen. I'm guessing this has to do with the driver being "experimental" and all, though I haven't faced any other major issue since installing. I would change the driver to a non-experimental one, but as you can see from the image, ubuntu isn't offering any alternative.

running the command `lspci | grep VGA` returns this output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8800M Series]
```

Any ideas what I should do\try?

**update**
I just installed the earlier non-experimental video drivers through synaptic and after rebooting, the problem still persists. What's the problem here?

**update2**
Alright, so I did two things. First, I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend), and after a failed resume and reboot I created a dmesg.txt file, which contained three mentions of `hash matches`:

```
[    1.766773]   Magic number: 0:665:273
[    1.766776]   hash matches /build/buildd/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/drivers/base/power/main.c:643
[    1.766798] tty tty10: hash matches
[    1.766804] net lo: hash matches
```

Second thing I did was run the command `dmesg | grep fglrx`, which returned this:

```
[   12.203459] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   12.206400] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   12.210284] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 7634 MBytes.
[   12.210440] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 6823 count: 1
[   12.210639] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0x3000, size: 0x100
[   12.210748] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   12.210760] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 13.30.1 [Jan  8 2014] with 1 minors
[   42.760504] fglrx_pci 0000:03:00.0: irq 66 for MSI/MSI-X
[   42.760981] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1513
[   42.761024] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1514
[   42.761065] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1515
[   42.761152] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 66 Enabled
[   42.772492] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   42.772495] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f878000, size:4000 
[   42.772496] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f87c000, size:484000 
[   42.772497] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:7fff4000, size:c000
```

I'm thinking the `fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing` is the important part. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest beta version of the almost released Ubuntu 14.04 LTS solved the problem. It automatically recognized and activated the right drivers. Everything is smooth and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

See this, hope it helps.

[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS often get a black screen with mouse cursor when trying to resume from lock screen.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132219/ubuntu-12-04-lts-often-get-a-black-screen-with-mouse-cursor-when-trying-to-resum)

And - if possible - test suspend / resume from newer version 13.10, for example.

Comment: The description he gives is different from mine. For one thing, he can move the mouse and his computer responds to keyboard commands (I can't enter terminal, and Ctrl+Alt+Del doesn't do anything). but thanks anyway